# Sass builds/compiles very slowly (also using Compass)

Tags: ruby, build, sass, compass-sass

I'm using Sass 3.4.9, Compass 1.0.1, and Ruby 1.8.7. I don't believe I'm using Rails since when I run rails -v it says "Rails is not currently installed on this system" and instructs me on how to install it.

After upgrading Sass and Compass, the compile time is about 5 minutes. I would guess this is about an extra 2 minute increase from before. FYI, the previous build time of about 3 minutes is not unexpected since I'm working with a very large codebase. But very little has changed after I upgraded. I've looked around for answers and haven't found anything conclusive. I tried removing some @extend directives. That didn't work. What I would like is to understand what is causing the problem (i.e. especially if it's a Sass or Compass issue and what that specifically is) and what to do about it so I can return to the previous build time if not faster.

EDIT - I reverted Sass to 3.1.15 (kept Compass 1.0.1), and in fact the compile time took about 1.5 minutes.

The thread at https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1019 does not provide any solutions or any concrete explanations on the cause.

Comment: Revert back and see if it really was as fast as you remember.  It's certainly possible a performance regression was introduced, but if you can't single it out, it'll be very hard to address.  Without known values to compare against you'll just be flailing and never be satisfied.

Comment: Downgrading my Sass version resulted in a 1.5 minute compile time.

Comment: Posting here is not going to help you, this is a problem only the maintainers of Sass/Compass can solve.  Also, it is impossible to revert back to Sass 3.1 because Compass 1.0 requires at least Sass 3.3.